# Adding path to PATH environment variable using bash script in /etc/environment

Tags: package-management, login, scripts, deb, environment-variables

I need to add path to my executable application to PATH environment variable. Because I need to add path during .deb package installation, I should use [postinst script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62534/adding-post-deb-install-scripts) in debian package. After reading [Ubuntu official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and [Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) I decided to use `/etc/environment` file to add my application path due to system wide user access. Here is my bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~
echo 'PATH="$PATH:/path/to/my/bin"' >> /etc/environment
```

and here is `/etc/environment` content after executing postinst bash script:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/my/bin"
```

Now when I log out and try log in, [I stuck in login loop!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

**Update 1:**

I tested the approach for .profile in Home directory and it works fine! But I need to add the path for all users so I must use `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: You should symlink the executable to `/usr/bin` instead of depending of `$PATH`. Anyway, here is the answer: Place an executable script in `/etc/profile.d` that set `$PATH`

Comment: @Archuser I tested the approach for .profile in Home directory and it works fine! But I need to add the path for all users.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi as Arch user said, place an executable script in `/etc/profile.d/` with `.sh` extension (which is what you should do if you're doing this from a package - or how will you reliably undo the addition on package removal?)

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are executed for all users

Comment: @Archuser thanks for your answers. It works now. If you add your answers I can select it as answer.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that such a file should not be installed via postinst, but it should be installed as a package file the normal way - probably via debian/install. Or, if you go for a symlink instead, via debian/links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please avoid modifing system files. Instead you should place an executable script in `/etc/profile.d` (scripts in here got executed for every user) to change `$PATH` value.

```
/etc/profile.d/10-<package name>.sh
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/executable
```