# dpkg has an error with the post-installation script

Tags: bash, package-management, scripts, dpkg, deb

I am trying to test if my .deb package is installing correctly, but I always get this error:

```
dpkg (subprocess): cannot set security execution context for maintainer script: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package testpkg (--install):
 installed testpkg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 testpkg
```

What is this?
My postinst script looks like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x /usr/bin/testpkg
exit 0
```

I'm super confused

Comment: I think you should give us more informations, something like how you create your .deb package, which (L,X,K)Ubuntu version you're on and maybe your architecture

Comment: also you can't make a file executable who doesn't exist, that's why you get exit status 2, in your post script you define what to do before installing your package

Comment: @lucki1000, is there a way to see the actual error? I tried removing the chmod but the error persisted

Comment: provide please the steps who you made, to get your .deb package

Comment: Also I take back my second comment, after I saw this post https://askubuntu.com/a/62559/1206611, but you should really provide some more information about your build enviromment.